# Wrapped text getting merged with column values

Tags: tables, wrap, parbox

I am using the following code for a table which doesn't look pleasing at all. I was able to wrap text but it is getting merged in the values given in the column. Any help would be appreciated.

```
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{ccccc}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Years}} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Days}}                                                                                         
& \multirow{2}{*}{\parbox{4cm} {\centering \textbf{Sediment volume excavated 
in the year represented by the boundary of the corresponding range of 
years}}} \\ \cline{2-4}
                                     & \textbf{\parbox{1.5cm} 
{\centeringQ\textgreater{}10 (m\textsuperscript{3}/s)}} & 
\textbf{\parbox{1.5cm} {\centering10\textgreater{}Q\textgreater{}20 
(m\textsuperscript{3}/s)}} & \textbf{\parbox{1.5cm} {\centering 
Q\textgreater{}20 (m\textsuperscript{3}/s)}} &                         \\ 
\hline
2002-2003                                & 18                                
& 15                                                & 3                                 
& 486                                               \\ 
2003-2006                                & 25                                
& 18                                                & 7                                 
& 666                                               \\ 
2006-2010                                & 24                                
& 22                                                & 2                                 
& 217                                                \\ 
2010-2013                                & 29                                
& 19                                                & 10                                
& 126                                                \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Please post a full compilable code, not a screenshot of a snippet.

Answer (score 2):

Use the caption for that big chunk of text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx,caption}

\sisetup{per-mode=symbol}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering

\caption{Sediment volume excavated in the year represented by
  the boundary of the corresponding range of years}

\begin{tabular}{ccccc}
\toprule
Years & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Days (\si{\meter\cubed\per\second})} & Sediment \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-4}
& $Q<10$ & $10<Q<20$ & $Q>20$ \\
\midrule
2002-2003 & 18 & 15 &  3 & 486 \\
2003-2006 & 25 & 18 &  7 & 666 \\
2006-2010 & 24 & 22 &  2 & 217 \\
2010-2013 & 29 & 19 & 10 & 126 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`\multirow` deliberately overlaps the next row (or several rows).  What you need is a strut to push the THIRD row down, which means it has to go on the second row.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[]
\sbox0{\parbox[t]{4cm}{\centering \textbf{Sediment volume excavated 
in the year represented by the boundary of the corresponding range of 
years}}}% measuer height
\begin{tabular}{ccccc}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Years}} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Days}}                                                                                         
& \multirow{2}{*}{\usebox0} \\
\cline{2-4}
& \textbf{\parbox[t]{1.5cm} 
{\centering Q\textgreater{}10 (m\textsuperscript{3}/s)}} & 
\textbf{\parbox[t]{1.5cm} {\centering 10\textgreater{}Q\textgreater{}20 
(m\textsuperscript{3}/s)}} & \textbf{\parbox[t]{1.5cm} {\centering 
Q\textgreater{}20 (m\textsuperscript{3}/s)}} & 
\rule[\dimexpr \arraystretch\normalbaselineskip-\dp0]{0pt}{0pt} \\ 
\hline
2002-2003                                & 18                                
& 15                                                & 3                                 
& 486                                               \\ 
2003-2006                                & 25                                
& 18                                                & 7                                 
& 666                                               \\ 
2006-2010                                & 24                                
& 22                                                & 2                                 
& 217                                                \\ 
2010-2013                                & 29                                
& 19                                                & 10                                
& 126                                                \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

---

This version moves the first row down.  Note that I used `\raisebox` this time.  `\multirow` always tries to center the entry, which we definitely do NOT want here.  To overlay the second row, I need to set the depth to 0pt, which can be done using the optional arguments.

It is important to remember where the baseline is for these adjustments, especially when using `\parbox`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[]
\sbox0{\parbox[b]{4cm}{\centering \strut\textbf{Sediment volume excavated 
in the year represented by the boundary of the corresponding range of 
years}}}% measure height
\sbox1{\textbf{\parbox[t]{1.5cm} 
{\centering Q\textgreater{}10 (m\textsuperscript{3}/s)}}}%
\begin{tabular}{ccccc}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Years}} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Days}}                                                                                         
& \raisebox{\dimexpr -\dp0-\ht1-\dp1}%
    [\dimexpr \ht0-\dp0-\ht1-\dp1][0pt]{\usebox0} \\
\cline{2-4}
& \usebox1 & 
\textbf{\parbox[t]{1.5cm} {\centering 10\textgreater{}Q\textgreater{}20 
(m\textsuperscript{3}/s)}} & \textbf{\parbox[t]{1.5cm} {\centering 
Q\textgreater{}20 (m\textsuperscript{3}/s)}} & \\ 
\hline
2002-2003                                & 18                                
& 15                                                & 3                                 
& 486                                               \\ 
2003-2006                                & 25                                
& 18                                                & 7                                 
& 666                                               \\ 
2006-2010                                & 24                                
& 22                                                & 2                                 
& 217                                                \\ 
2010-2013                                & 29                                
& 19                                                & 10                                
& 126                                                \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: second demo]

---

This time I put another tabular inside the tabular and used `\makebox` in one row to match the column widths.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[]
\sbox0{\begin{tabular}{@{}p{1.5cm}p{1.5cm}p{1.5cm}@{}}
  \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Days}} \\
  \hline
  \centering\textbf{Q\textgreater{}10 (m\textsuperscript{3}/s)} &
  \centering\textbf{10\textgreater{}Q\textgreater{}20 (m\textsuperscript{3}/s)} &
  \centering\textbf{Q\textgreater{}20 (m\textsuperscript{3}/s)}
\end{tabular}}% savebox not really needed here
\begin{tabular}{ccccc}
\hline
\textbf{Years} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\usebox0} & 
\parbox{4cm}{\centering \strut\textbf{Sediment volume excavated 
in the year represented by the boundary of the corresponding range of 
years}\strut} \\
\hline
2002-2003 & \makebox[1.5cm]{18} & \makebox[1.5cm]{15} & \makebox[1.5cm]{3} & 486 \\ 
2003-2006                                & 25                                
& 18                                                & 7                                 
& 666                                               \\ 
2006-2010                                & 24                                
& 22                                                & 2                                 
& 217                                                \\ 
2010-2013                                & 29                                
& 19                                                & 10                                
& 126                                                \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo 3]

Comment: Perfect! Could the headings 'years' and 'days' also be aligned w.r.t the thirst heading, so that it looks cleaner? Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: You want them at the bottom instead of the top?

Comment: In the middle, actually, like in excel.